# How to redirect python stdout to log file by using pybind 11 in c++

Tags: python, c++, object, methods, pybind11

I want to redirect python stdout to write it in log file by using pybind11.

From the pybind11 docs found py::scoped_ostream_redirect method.

I would like to do the following:

```
py::scoped_ostream_redirect stream(
    py::module_::import("sys").attr("stdout"),
    log()                               

);
```

redirect stdout to log(), where log is a c++ object.

As I understand scoped_ostream_redirect is used to redirect c++ stream to python. I need to do reverse thing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

sys.stdout can be assigned to any class' instance which contains write and flush methods.

```
class Logger
{
public:
   void write(std::string str){
   // write here where you want to write the content of print function
       log.write(str);
   }

   void flush(){
       std::cout << std::flush();
   }
}
```

Here you need to add the class to the python module.

```
PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(embeded, module) 
{
    py::class_<LogWriter>(module, "Writer")
        .def("write", &Logger::write)
        .def("flush", &Logger::flush);
 }

void main(){
    py::module::import("embedded");
    Logger logger;       
    py::module::import("sys").attr("stdout") = logger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be required for using a stdout stream when a console belongs to a dll on windows - not sure entirely might be related to how windows handles things?

Here is my minimal example based on the solution above, worked for me printf can be replaced with a file write. This is mostly what was posted above but some things maybe needed to change for C++17/latest pybind11

originally I had tried to assign a buffer object python sys.stdout

Hopefully this helps someone.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/iostream.h"
#include "pybind11/embed.h"


namespace py = pybind11;
bool init = true;

class PyStdout
{
public:
    void write(std::string str) {
        //write to file here 
        printf("%s", str.c_str());
    }

    void flush() {
        fflush(stdout);
    }
};

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(embeded, module)
{
    py::class_<PyStdout>(module, "stdout")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("write", &PyStdout::write)
        .def("flush", &PyStdout::flush);
}


DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    printf("[+] entering main... \n");
    
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    //import python module to execute functions from
    auto mod = py::module::import("scripts.main");
    auto update = mod.attr("update");
    update();
    return 0;

}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    
    if (init) {
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
        
        init = false;
        printf("[+] startup \n");

    }


    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, MainThread, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:        
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

then from the python module

```
import io
import sys
import os
import embeded

def update():
    log_out = embeded.stdout()
    log_err = embeded.stdout()
    sys.stdout = log_out
    sys.stderr = log_err
    print("something to log here")
```